# How to use multiple properties of an object in an array depending on user input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const cities = [
{
    id: 0,
    city: "Buenos Aires",
    country: "Argentina",
    codeIATA: "AEP",
    aeroName: "Aeroparque Internacional Jorge Newbery",
    coordX: 15,
    coordY: 36,
},
{
    id: 1,
    city: "El Calafate",
    country: "Argentina",
    codeIATA: "FTE",
    aeroName: "Aeropuerto Internacional Comandante Armando Tola de El Calafate",
    coordX: -49,
    coordY: -63,
},
]

let origin = parseInt(prompt("ID Origen"));
let destination = parseInt(prompt("ID Destino"));
```

Inside an array I have multiple objects like the ones above. The user will select one of the objects for origin and the other for destination by entering 0 or 1 or whichever ID of objects that I will have. I'm guessing I'll have to match the number with the index or id inside the object to select it.

Once the object is selected for origin and destination I want to select the coordX and coordY of each and calculate the distance between each point (I already have the formula for that). I know how to do the math but I'm struggling to fetch the coordinates depending on which object the user selects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cities.find` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) to find the city object with the `id` entered by the user:

```
const origin = 1;
const originCity = cities.find((city) => city.id === origin);
```